# Can an user see their post deleted for reasons of moderation and its comments?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-questions, notifications

As it often happens, a new user posts a thank you answer or asks a question in answer box, people leave comments under them telling them to ask new questions or leaving other related links and flag them. The post gets deleted some time later.

Is the poster now able to see the deleted answer and the comments under it or do they just disappear like comments?  If not, commenting would be a waste.

Are the notifications about comments still there in the notification box or do they have to visit their posts sections to reach that answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't get a notification about the deleted answer, but they do get a notification from the comments by the ♦ moderator. That's why I tend to leave a comment whenever I delete a post. As a regular user, you should still leave comments because the author might read them before their post gets deleted. Some more details can be found in [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231990/295232).

As you hinted at, there is some functionality to see your own recently deleted posts: the [Answers tab on your profile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers) contains a link at the bottom to view them. The same functionality exists for questions.

Comment: I always leave a comment in situations like this for the very reason you mentioned: the OP might see the comments before the post is deleted.  My goal is to provide some constructive feedback to the user on why I voted the way I did and how they can have a better chance at getting their problem resolved or question answered.